# Constant reference as a class member

Tags: c++

Lets say that I have the following class:

```
class BigClass
{
public:
    BigClass();
    ~BigClass();

private:
    ... // many variables
};
```

And another class:

```
class SmallClass
{
public:
    SmallClass();
    ~SmallClass();

private:
    const BigClass &ref;
};
```

Notice that I have a reference to a `BigClass` object called `ref`.

- Is that a good design ? Is there a better way to do that ?
- What is gonna happen when the actual `BigClass` object gets out of scope ? Will it be deleted or will it stay alive because of the `ref` reference to it ? If it gets deleted, then a good way to do keep it alive would be to have a `shared_ptr` instead of a reference ?

Comment: In order to tell you if it is okay or not what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `Is there a better way to do that?` To do what? You didnt tell us what you actaully want to achieve but only told us about your solution. Once the `BigClass` object goes out of scope, you should not use the reference anymore. Why arent you using a some sort of smarpointer?

Comment: @NathanOliver Storing something smaller than a copy of the `BigClass` object itself (like a reference or a pointer), as a class member.

Comment: thats still not really clear. I mean a good way to store a reference is to store a reference, yes. But what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Okay but what semantics to do need?  Do you need to modify it?  Share it?  Copy it?  Do you want your class to be copyable?

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to access its public properies.

Comment: Is it possible for the `BigClass` object to go out of scope before `SmallClass` does and if so what do you want to have happen?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am asking what is the default behavior when that does happen, and how often do you see constant references to objects as class members. If this was java or C#, I would simple have `BigClass ref;`, since that is actually a memory address. So, in c++, to do that I would use `const BigClass &ref;` to have the equivalent result ? Or perhaps should have I wrapped the actual object in a `shared_ptr`, and also another `shared_ptr` in the `SmallClass` instead of a constant reference ?

Comment: I think this will be an accident waiting to happen. Few code changes, new developer and remembering that one object lifetime depends on another goes out of the windows.  Use a copy or smart pointers

Comment: This is one of the things that the Rust language http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info does really well. Track references and guarantee that you are using them correctly. If you use them wrong the program won't even compile. If this is a new project you might want to try Rust first.

Comment: @ZanLynx Huh, that's interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that a good design ? Is there a better way to do that ?

If SmallClass is guaranteed to have a shorter lifetime than BigClass then it is perfectly fine. This kind of thing is often seen in small classes used as "functors."

Otherwise use a smart pointer: unique or shared. Or weak shared.

> What is gonna happen when the actual BigClass object gets out of scope ?

If SmallClass still exists and has the reference, it is now an invalid reference and your program will have undefined behavior. That's bad. It probably won't crash but using the reference will write over another object or corrupt the heap's free memory tracking, or overwrite stack values including possibly the function return address.

> Will it be deleted or will it stay alive because of the ref reference to it ?

This is not Java. It will be deleted. If you need to track reference counts then you need a shared smart pointer.

> If it gets deleted, then a good way to do keep it alive would be to have a shared_ptr instead of a reference ?

Yes.

Comment: Would I have to wrap the initial actual object in a `shared_ptr` as well ? And also change the constant reference to `shared_ptr` ?

Comment: I am basically asking if I can create a `shared_ptr` to a stack object that I created beforehand.

Comment: @Shiro: You'll need to read about smart pointers in C++11. You'll probably want to use `make_shared`. Do not mix using raw pointers and shared pointers to the same object. If you mix then you lose the benefit of the reference counting.

Comment: Ah........ I just remembered about `std::make_shared`. That's what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @Shiro: If you restrict yourself to using the stack and your object's pointers are never copied to the heap then you can enforce the correct use of that SmallClass object.

Comment: @Shiro: You do not want to make shared_ptrs to stack objects because the shared_ptr can't control deleting it. It will be deleted when the stack ends.

Comment: Oh really. So do I have to wrap the object in a `shared_ptr` when creating it, instead of creating it in the stack ?

Comment: @Shiro: Decide how you want to manage its lifetime. Stack or Heap. If you use Heap it won't be destroyed on function exit. That's when you want the shared_ptr. If you only need it to survive during a function call then things are simple and you don't need smart pointers.

Comment: And by `you don't need smart pointers` you mean that the constant reference becomes ok ? or even preferred ?

Comment: @Shiro: I think that's pretty clear in my answer to your question about what happens if BigClass goes out of scope. Make sure SmallClass goes out of scope first.